# consumerProguardFiles with proguard file dose not work for library

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

My pojo files are `data calss` written by kotlin, I want to obfuse most of my library code except the pojo files becasue Gson needs them since Gson use reflection.

When I use `./gradlew :library:assembleRelease`, the `aar` file generates in `library/build/outputs/aar`, then I drag it to IDE window to inspect the aar structure, there is no `pojo` folder, obviously been obfused.

[This is the code structre been decompiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrcqm.png)

#### This is the rule

-keep class com.test.activation.pojo.** { *; }

#### build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            consumerProguardFiles 'lib-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

However when I add @Keep annotation to the pojo, then the class it not obfused.

Any one face the same issue?